# Bug? In PyQt5 implementing rowCount() for a QStandardItemModel has strange effects

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I just wanted to implement against `QStandardItemModel` and tried to make `rowCount()` return |rows| + 1 to show an extra line.
I would have implemented `data()` and `flags()` accordingly to show valid values for the extra line.

But now I'm confused. The extra line gets drawed (so the method is implemented correctly) but `data()` and `flags()` will *always* be called with an index inside the internal data model.
Additionally my app crashes in about 50% of cases.

So it looks like `rowCount()` is not used for every case where it *should* be used, which leads to invalid access to the internal data..

Is this a bug?

I'm using PyQt5-5.14.0 on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem("Hi"), QtGui.QStandardItem("there")])
        self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem("Hello"), QtGui.QStandardItem("world")])

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return super().rowCount() + 1

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        assert index.row() < 2  # index.row() is always in [-1, 0, 1]
        return super().data(index, role)

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags:
        assert index.row() < 2  # index.row() is always in [-1, 0, 1]
        return super().flags(index)


class Testing(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        model = MyModel()
        view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        view.setModel(model)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    test = Testing()
    raise SystemExit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to implement `index()`:

```
def index(self, row, column, parent):
    return super().index(row, column) if row < super().rowCount() else self.createIndex(row, column)
```

Explanation: `super().index()` would create in invalid index for rows > |internal data| which results in `flags()` or `data()` not being called at all.